# Matlab error: Array indices must be positive integers or logical values

Tags: matlab, histogram

I'm trying to do a normalized histogram on Matlab and I keep getting this error and I don't understand why

This is the part where I'm getting the error

```
    
    k;
    framecito= Frame(k);
    acum_normal= Histograma_acum_norm(framecito);
    Salida(k) = framecito*acum_normal;
end
```

Frame is a 1280*720 bits vector, Histograma_acum_norm is a 255 vector and Salida(k) well is the large of K

Any help is really useful, thank you

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Ok I will try, thanks for the comment

Comment: From the error though, you should be able to debug and see whether it's `k` or `framecito` which is not a "positive integer or logical value" as stated in the error

Comment: Thank you so much for the feedback. That seemed to be the problem. Sorry for my bad question I didn't know how to put a reproducible code because it depended on other functions

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Nevertheless, my guess is that index "k" or "framecito" are starting at value 0 or receiving some non-integer value, when vectors and arrays in MATLALB **only** have positive integer positions (ie.: Frame(1), Frame(2), Frame(3) or Histograma_acum_norm(1), Histograma_acum_norm(2) etc)